# Recursive integration

Tags: python, function, recursion

This is a simplified version of the actual question I am working on.

Suppose that we have a sequence of (mathematical) functions, f_0, f_1, f_2, ..., such that
[image]

We fix a function f_0, say, f_0(x)=x. In this simple case, f_n(x) = 1/((n+1)!) x^{n+1}. Is there an elegant and efficient way to program this recursively, so that Python returns the function f_n given **an arbitrary** function f_0?

I started out trying to return f_2, but this already failed:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

f_0=lambda x: x
f_1=lambda x: quad(f_0,0,x)
f_2=lambda x: quad(f_1,0,x)
```

returns the error

```
error: Supplied function does not return a valid float.
```

after trying to evaluate e.g. f_2(3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with chaining numeric integrals. The problem is what `quad` returns:

> Returns:
>   **y** : float
>      The integral of func from a to b.
>
> **abserr** : float
>      An estimate of the absolute error in the result.

So you get two return values but only the first one is interesting (unless you want to propagate the error over all integrals, but I don't know how to do that). The second integral complains because the function returns a tuple of two values instead of only one scalar.

The following small modification will fix the error by selecting the first of `quad`'s return values:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

f_0=lambda x: x
f_1=lambda x: quad(f_0,0,x)[0]
f_2=lambda x: quad(f_1,0,x)[0]
```

For the sake of completeness, here is a recursive definition for iterating n times:

```
def integrate_a_lot(f, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        f = lambda x, f=f: quad(f, 0, x)[0]
    return f

f_2 = integrate_a_lot(f_0, 2)
f_42 = integrate_a_lot(f_0, 42)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I completely forgot about the second output value!

In order to iterate this up until arbitrary n, I tried to define the "new f" in terms of the old f, i.e.:

f=lambda x: x;
f=lambda x: quad(f,0,x)[0];
f=lambda x: quad(f,0,x)[0];

but this gives the error: maximum recursion depth exceeded. 

Do you know a convenient way to iterate this an arbitrary number of times (without saving f_1,f_2,...,f_{n-1})?

Comment: @user1162809 Yes, the recursion thing happens because `f` inside the function is only looked up on execution, at which point it is the function itself. Do this instead: `f=lambda x: x` `f=lambda x, f=f: quad(f,0,x)[0]` `f=lambda x, f=f: quad(f,0,x)[0]`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: The only downside to this is that it is not efficient. For n=10, Python is already struggling. But possibly this is something that cannot be avoided if one wants to compute high-dimensional convolutions....

Comment: @user1162809 Good to hear. I have edited this information into the answer for completeness' sake.

Comment: @user1162809 Performance is a problem because numeric integration is a relatively accureate but slow procedure. You can maybe get performance improvements if you are able to discretize your integrals - but this is getting waaay out of my dephts and becoming rather off-topic too :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use sympy: http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/integrals/integrals.html
something like

```
x = sympy.Symbol('x')

def f_0(m_x):
    return m_x

def f_n(f_0,n,m_x):
    if n==0:
        return f_0(m_x)
    return sympy.integrate(f_n(f_0(m_x),n-1,m_x))
```

then call it with f_n(f_0,1,x)

Comment: Shouldn't it be "return x" rather than just "x"? And n=0 should be n==0? Furthermore, sympy is for symbolic integration. In general I cannot assume that f_0 has a symbolic integral, and hence the numerical integrals.

Comment: yah, I made some minor revisions.  If you don't want to use symbolic integration, then you can use scipy.integrate in a similar manner (just have to pass limits)

Comment: True, it is not very straightforward how to pass all the boundaries for arbitrary n, but I will try this.